# How to replace wordpress css or js file with external file?

Tags: css

I would like to replace WordPress style.css file or any other files like this with style.css file in an external host
How can I do this?
Of course, I saw this tutorial before

https://css-tricks.com/methods-overriding-styles-wordpress/

but I don't know how can I replace this external file with my basic theme files like style.css or like this

For example this code can be

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://external-host.com/css/style.css' type='text/css'/>
```

instead of

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://mywebsite.com/wp-includes/css/style.css' type='text/css'/>
```

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Can you add some context for why you are doing this and what the problem it sovles is? How are the styles currently added to WP? It's unclear if you're trying to make WP load external styles, or if WP is loading external styles and you want to replace them with local ones?

Comment: tom-j-nowell to reduce load speed website I would like  to send some of my CSS and js code to the external host, but this CSS file is in my WordPress and my website is not able to read my external file, because of conflict both of them, this can make an error and when I want to use a new edit in my external file, this cannot make a change in my website

Comment: Can you include the code that loads your CSS in your question? There's not enough information to answer this at the moment. Can you give examples? It's still unclear

Comment: code can be  <link  rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://www.external-host.com/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>    instead of <link  rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-includes/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>

Comment: I think Tom meant the PHP code that generates the HTML, not the HTML itself.

Comment: Ah, the OP didn't share the code because they don't have any code to share, this is a generic "WP enqueued stuff locally, how do I override it to a 3rd party domain". TBH this will probably make your site slower not faster, especially if you're using http2 ( you'll be eliminating a lot of the advantages of HTTP2 such as multiplexing, parallel downloads and requests etc ). It sounds like you ran your site through a pagespeed style tool online that then gave you outdated advice such as use multiple domains for performance

Comment: @RedScience I presume you have all the styles and JS assets already mirrored on an external domain? Is it possible you're trying ot implement a CDN but haven't shared that information? You're question is still not clear, I know it seems as if you've stated what you want, but it's ambiguous and judging from the answers/comments people don't understand what or why

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you want to override some particular CSS properties from style.css of a WordPress theme.

There might be two different situations here which needs different solutions:

1. If you are developing your own theme then you can simply edit your functions.php inside your theme files and add any JS or CSS file that you want like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'handle name', 'your external source address');
wp_enqueue_script( 'handle name', 'your external source address');
```

I don't know if you are familiar with WordPress developing conventions but you have to wrap this function inside a custom one and call that after a WordPress hook like this:

```
function custom_function() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'handle name', 'your external source address' )
    wp_enqueue_script( 'handle name', 'your external source address' )
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_function' );
```

2. If you are using a theme from the official WordPress repository, then it is not a good practice to make changes to files of that theme, because most likely you will lose all your custom changes when that theme gets updated. Instead, you have to make a child theme for that theme and do as explained previously for functions.php of the child theme.

Defining a child theme is a different topic on it's own but it's not a difficult one! Study this page and you will be able to make your own child theme easily:

[Child Themes | Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

other useful related resources:

[wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

[wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: NO , I would like to replace CSS or js link with an external link

Comment: @RedScience you override the enqueued assets in order to replace them. Overriding and replacing are the same thing

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific hook you can use for the theme's stylesheet, [stylesheet_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/stylesheet_uri/):

```
function wpse350851_override_stylesheet_uri( $stylesheet, $stylesheet_dir ) {
    return 'http://external-host.com/css/style.css';
}
apply_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', 'wpse350851_override_stylesheet_uri', 10, 2 );
```

Note you probably need to switch between HTTP and HTTPS URLs e.g. using [is_ssl()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl)), or just use HTTPS by default.

Comment: how we can disable to run internal theme style.css file?

Comment: It's normally in your theme's header.php. Something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
`. If your theme doesn't provide a header.php then WordPress has a default one in wp-includes\theme-compat.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and found another way to override entire stylesheets. It's quite straightforward.

I used this method on a theme that included a large CSS library file that also referenced other unoptimised assets. The whole thing was terrible for performance but the site still depended on some of its functionality.

The solution was to look through the plugin code and/or the HTML output to find the `$handle` parameter passed to [`wp_register_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) (or `wp_enqueue_style()`), then register using that same handle. You do this by attaching to the same hook with a lower priority, or an earlier hook, than the one in which the original is registered. You register *but do not enqueue* your own version. This causes the original's registration to fail, but it should still enqueue yours because of the same handle.

To demonstrate, the theme registers the problematic style in a setup class:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'queueStyles']);
    ...
}
...
public function queueStyles()
{
    ...
    wp_register_style(
        'slow-lib',
        get_theme_file_uri('css/slow.css'),
        [],
        '2.7.3'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style('slow-lib');
    ...
}
```

This produces output like so:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slow-lib-css' href='https://simple.example/wp-content/themes/some-theme/css/slow.css?ver=2.7.3' media='all' />
```

In a basic custom plugin, I have optimised versions of the the assets (images, etc.) and refer to them in my own file. I then usurp the registration:

```php
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    function() {
        # can add extra conditionals here if you need to make exceptions where the original should load
        wp_register_style(
            'slow-lib', # same handle
            plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'fast.css',
            [], # same as original $deps parameter
            '2.7.3' # anything, but best to keep track of which version you modified
        );
    },
    -10, # lower priority than theme
    0
);
```

The output changes to this:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slow-lib-css' href='https://simple.example/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/fast.css?ver=2.7.3' media='all' />
```

The original files are never loaded, but the replacements appear in the same place and satisfy the same dependencies. You can use any URL in your registration, including externally hosted files.